# Doctrine2 join column

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have defined the follow entity in doctrine2 (with symfony).

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="order")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order

 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="personid", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $personid;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="People")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personid", referencedColumnName="personid")
 */
private $person;


public function getPersonId()
{
    return $this->personid;
}
public function getPerson()
{
    return $this->person;
}

}
```

I realize that if I call $order->getPersonId() it return always an empty value and I have to call the getPerson()->getId() method to get the correct personid.
Could anyone explain me why the variable $personid is not filled? 
Should I to delete the column id used for the join if I defined one?

Thanks

Gisella

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `private $personid;`, it's better to work with objects only in an ORM.

It's not a problem if you get the ID with `$order->getPerson()->getId()`, because Doctrine won't load the complete entity. The `People` entity will only be loaded if you call an other field than the join key.

You can still have a getter shortcut like this :

```
public function getPersonId()
{
    return $this->getPerson()->getId();
}
```

---

Edit :
You can also still work with "ID" if you use Doctrine references, like  this :

```
$order->setPerson($em->getReference('YourBundle:People', $personId));
```

With this way, Doctrine won't perform a `SELECT` query to load data of the person.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You suggested a nice workaround. Anyway I use to set the $personid instead of the People object, usually when I create new Order object. Is it still correct?

Comment: I updated my answer : you can use `getReference()` with the `EntityManager` if you want to work only with your ID.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the $personid field when you already have the $person field.
$people contains the People object (with all People's attributes including the id).

Moreover, when doctrine translate your object into sql tables, he knows that he have to join with th id so it will create a field (in database) named personid. (It's the name that you defined in your ORM)

```
  /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="People")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personid", referencedColumnName="personid")
 */
private $person;
```

Sorry for bad english :p