# Doctrine 2 mapping: 2 fields for the 1 database column

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

I want to have an alternative approach of the relationship referencing for each my Doctrine 2 entity: each entity relationship can be instantiated via **id field** or via **reference field**, and both fields mapped to the same database column.

Let me show:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Column(name = "REF_ID", type = "integer", nullable = false)
 */
private $refId;

/**
 * @var IBlock
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity = "Ref")
 * @JoinColumn(name = "REF_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
 */
private $ref;
```

Whet I call persist for the such entity:

```
 $entity = new Entity();
 $entity->setName("Test entity");
 $entity->setRefId(14);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Column 'REF_ID' cannot be null
```

How can I implement workaround this? Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I've found relevant answer. I need just to use a proxy reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559685/doctrine2-join-column/31559793

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `$ref` attribute also, as example:

```
  // Retrieve the $ref entity object as example with the repository
 $ref = $refRepo->find(14)

  //or
  // $ref = $em->getRepository('Entity')->find($id);
  // as described here in the doc
  // http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-primary-key

 $entity = new Entity();
 $entity->setName("Test entity");
 $entity->setRefId(14);
 $entity->setRef($ref);
```

Hope this help